# What was Rhodesia like before independence?

Tags: colonization, africa, independence, zimbabwe, rhodesia

I have heard a lot about Robert Mugabe in my time, and he mostly seemed like a good example of how not to run a country. Now that he's died, I'm seeing a lot of articles talking about his supposed "heroic" side. He fought for the country's independence, and I understand how that must have been seen as a heroic and noble achievement, but I have a hard time believing that the country and it's people were in a worse place before his rise to power.

From what I can tell he ran the country into the ground, even if his initial goal may have been a good one.

So I've been wondering, what was Rhodesia like before independence? And what kind of oppression was the country suffering from before independence? How bad was colonial rule in 1980 before independence?

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? What did you find? Please help us to help you. You might find it helpful to review the [site tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question to explain what you think is missing from, or unclear about the Wikipedia article on the [History of Rhodesia (1965–79)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Rhodesia_(1965%E2%80%9379))?

Comment: Rhodesia's white rulers unilaterally declared independence in 1965, even though only apatheid South Africa ever recognized it. So, Rhodesia was "independent" well before Mugabe. Mugabe fought for majority rule, not independence.

Comment: Could the question be salvaged if OZp documents preliminary research?